# Writing MIDI-sequence into file with custom soundbank

Tags: java, audio

My program must receive input MIDI-sequence and replace original instruments with my custom soundbank instruments and write it into the .mid file. I am able to replace instruments with `javax.sound.midi.Synthesizer` and play them but can't mind out how to replace them and save the modified midi-sequence into file.

Sample code:

```
Soundbank soundbank = MidiSystem.getSoundbank(new File("path to soundbank"));
Synthesizer synthesizer = MidiSystem.getSynthesizer();
synthesizer.open();
synthesizer.loadAllInstruments(soundbank);

Player player = new Player(synthesizer);
org.jfugue.Pattern pattern = new org.jfugue.Pattern(
        "$PP=0 T120 V0 I42 C4ww V1 I[PP] C5w+E5qq_G5qq C5w+E5qq_G5qq C5w+A"
      + "5qq_g5qq C5w+A5qq_g5qq V2 I43 G3q G3q G3q G3q G3q G3q G3q G3q V9 81q"
);

Rhythm rhythm = new Rhythm();
rhythm.setLayer(1, "O..oO...O..oOO..");
rhythm.setLayer(2, "..*...*...*...*.");
rhythm.setLayer(3, "^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^");
rhythm.setLayer(4, "...............!");

//Here the piano is replaced with an instrument from my soundbank
rhythm.addSubstitution('O', "[PIANO]i");
rhythm.addSubstitution('o', "Rs [BASS_DRUM]s");
rhythm.addSubstitution('*', "[ACOUSTIC_SNARE]i");
rhythm.addSubstitution('^', "[PEDAL_HI_HAT]s Rs");
rhythm.addSubstitution('!', "[CRASH_CYMBAL_1]s Rs");
rhythm.addSubstitution('.', "Ri");
Pattern rpattern = rhythm.getPattern();

rpattern.repeat(2);
pattern.add(rpattern);
player.play(pattern);

player.saveMidi(pattern, new File("file.mid"));
```

When I run this program, I hear the instruments from my soundbank, but the `player.saveMidi()` method writes the melody with the original instruments.

Comment: It would be better if you could show what is it that you tried and tell what does not work. Please appreciate that StackOverflow contributors have very limited time.

Comment: @Alessandro I corrected the post.